# Issues running JScript or VBScript files with UTF-8 encoding thru Windows Script Host

Tags: windows, utf-8, vbscript, jscript, wsh

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I can't seem to run the following JScript through the `Windows Script Host` if I save it in a `.js` file with the `UTF-8` encoding:

```
var name = "Hello world!";
WScript.echo(name);
```

When I run it, it gives me this error:

[image]

Note that the script runs fine if I save it with `ANSI` encoding.

Is `Windows Script Host` engine not compatible with the `UTF-8` encoding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible source file encodings for VBScript and JScript are ANSI or UTF-16 (LE). UTF-8 can't be used.

Comment: Yes, that would be my guess too.

Comment: Is there any official documentation on this?

Comment: It would be great to know if this is officially documented anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you can save your file as [Windows Script File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15x4407c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (`.wsf`). Apparently, the Windows Script Host does accept XML that is encoded in UTF-8. The script from the question would be written in a WSF as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<job>
<script language="JScript"><![CDATA[
    var name = "Hello world!";
    WScript.echo(name);
]]></script>
</job>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<job>
<script language="JScript" src="Your-UTF-8-File.js" />
</job>
```

First problem is that BOM is necessary in js file. Second problem is that I have found no way to enable JScript 5.8 mode from WSF, and Chakra does not work from WSF either. But I use this anyway.

**UPD.** I have found a better solution: I have a bootloader which conforms to ugly WScript requirements, and inside of it I am reading files with ADODB.Stream in UTF-8 and eval() them, and this way I can run UTF-8 JavaScript without BOM even on Chakra!